# What is the meaning of children playing with sun rays in Le Meraviglie?

Tags: analysis, the-wonders

A couple times in the movie, two sisters play with sun rays. Is there any symbol or allegory in these scenes?

This question comes from the "special" games in the scenes. In one, the older sister asks the younger to "drink" the sun rays. In another one, they step on sun spots on the ground. The scenes do not look gratuitous on the settings.